# Connect to IDevices through bluetooth or Wifi

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there any api to let us make a connection between two IPads/Iphones through wifi/bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you want to do.  If its for a game then the GameKit APIs allow for this.  Check the Game Kit programming guide below -

[GameKit Programming Guide - Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: it's not only for game, i want to share some data between that devices

Comment: Have a look at this sample code from Apple, I think it may help you out.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html